# Ionic 6 capacitor community electron - Using awesome cordova plugins

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, electron, cordova-plugins, capacitor

I have started a new project using Ionic 6 Angular. I have added package `@capacitor-community/electron` in order to develop a windows *.appx* app. I'm able to run it, pack it, etc.

I need to create a file on a button click and I would like to store it where the app is installed (dataDirectory). I've tried to use `@capacitor/filesystem`, but I cannot make it work, nothing happens.

Then I saw I could make use of `@awesome-cordova-plugins/file`, so I've tried it as well and if I print `file.dataDirectory`, I get always null. I've tried to use `writeFile(...)` to create the file, but without success...

My steps to install `@awesome-cordova-plugins/file` are:

1. `npm install  @awesome -cordova-plugins/core --save`
2. `npm install  @awesome -cordova-plugins/file`
3. Then I have imported and added the plugin provider in the NgModule and injected the class from the /ngx directory (like mentioned in the [package description](https://github.com/danielsogl/awesome-cordova-plugins#ionicangular-apps))
4. After all that, `ionic build && npx cap sync @capacitor-community/electron` to have the changes on electron.

**Packages installed**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "15.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "15.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "15.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "15.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "15.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "15.2.3",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "6.3.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/file": "6.3.0",
    "@capacitor-community/electron": "4.1.2",
    "@capacitor/app": "4.1.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "4.7.1",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "4.1.1",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "4.1.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "6.6.3",
    "ionicons": "6.0.3",
    "rxjs": "7.8.0",
    "tslib": "2.5.0",
    "zone.js": "0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "15.2.4",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "15.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "15.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "15.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "15.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "15.2.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "15.2.3",
    "@capacitor/cli": "4.7.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "8.0.0",
    "@types/node": "18.15.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.56.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.56.0",
    "eslint": "8.36.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "40.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
    "ts-node": "8.3.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
```

**CODE THAT DOESN'T WORK**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { File } from "@awesome-cordova-plugins/file/ngx";
import { Directory, Filesystem } from "@capacitor/filesystem";
import { Platform } from "@ionic/angular";

@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "home.page.html",
  styleUrls: ["home.page.scss"],
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(private file: File, private platform: Platform) {}

  async createFileWithCordovaPlugin() {
    await this.platform.ready();

    const localStatePath = `${this.file.dataDirectory}/LocalState`;

    try {
      const fileExists = await this.file.checkFile(localStatePath, "ip.txt");
      if (!fileExists) {
        await this.file.writeFile(localStatePath, "test.txt", "TEST");
        window.alert(`Path: ${localStatePath}`);
      }
    } catch {}
  }

  async createFileWithCapacitorPlugin() {
    await this.platform.ready();

    const localStatePath = Directory.Data;

    try {
      await Filesystem.writeFile({
        path: "test.txt",
        data: "TEST",
        directory: localStatePath,
      });
      window.alert(`Path: ${localStatePath}`);
    } catch {}
  }
}
```

**INVOKED BY**

```
  <ion-button (click)="createFileWithCapacitorPlugin()">CAPACITOR</ion-button>
  <ion-button (click)="createFileWithCordovaPlugin()">CORDOVA</ion-button>
```

Am I doing anything wrong or missing anything? Maybe I can just make use of `capacitor/filesystem` package instead, but how?

Comment: Please post the code that doesn't work.

Comment: @E.Maggini I've just edited the description. Let me know if I can provide something else helpful... Thanks!

Comment: do you get any console output information? Maybe some errors thrown or have you tried to add debug info to ensure those paths exist?

Comment: In the window.alert, after I try to create the file, the `localStatePath` is null, as well as the rest of directory paths both plugins provide...

Comment: So far, it looks like @capacitor/filesystem is working, but stores the file in the indexeddb. I can write it and read it. Is there any possibility to store it in my package installation localState directory? @awesome-cordova-plugins/file is not working.